# How to get a prev/next | first/last button to work with list.js pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, list.js

I would like to add prev/next, first/last button to my already paginated and working index. Has anyone else created these buttons using List.js?

```html
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/2.4.1/lodash.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.1.1/list.min.js'></script>
<script src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.pagination.js/0.1.1/list.pagination.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>

<div class="nav">
  <ul class="pagination"></ul>
</div>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var options = {
      valueNames: ['prmodel', 'prcolor', 'prcapacity', 'prstorefilter'],
      page: 10,
      plugins: [ListPagination({})]
    };
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Funny fact, I've built a pagination tool as a part of my library... Feel free to check it out... Here's the [link](https://github.com/JO3-W3B-D3V/ToolKit-JS/blob/master/src/development/ToolKit.js#L119).

Comment: Thank you for your respond, great job, BRAVooo.. but it doesn't work on me, thank you for your help again

Comment: What exactly does your data look like? ... It's hard to say what's the best solution because all you've provided is very little HTML & JavaScript.

Comment: Siminlar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43123383).

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is still relevant but this is what I implemented. 'paginationCenter' is the  that shows the actual page numbers that I've defined in PaginationClass = "paginationCenter". You'll also need to set the 'previous button' to hide on page load. perPage is passed in as part of the options for page: perPage.

```
var perPage = 10;
var myList = new List('myList', options)
      .on("updated", function(list) {
          var current_page = Math.ceil(list.i/perPage);
          var total_pages = Math.ceil(list.matchingItems.length/perPage);
          
          if (total_pages > 1){
            $(".paginationCenter").show(true);
            switch(current_page) {
              case 1:
                $(".page-previous").hide(true);
                $(".page-next").show(true);
                break;
              case total_pages:
                $(".page-next").hide(true);
                $(".page-previous").show(true);
                break;
              default:
                $(".page-previous").show(true);
                $(".page-next").show(true);
                break;
            }
          } else {
            $(".paginationCenter").hide(true);
            $(".page-previous").hide(true);
            $(".page-next").hide(true);
          }
      });

// Trigger the previous / next page if the <- PREVIOUS or NEXT -> buttons are clicked
    $("ul.list-pagination-prev").click(function() {
      $(".paginationCenter .active").prev().trigger("click");
    });
    
    $("ul.list-pagination-next").click(function() {
      $(".paginationCenter .active").next().trigger("click");
    });
```